# Create a Clojurescript namespace dynamically in a macro?

Tags: clojurescript

Can I write a Clojurescript macro that defines a function in another namespace?

Defining the function in the namespace where the macro is used is easy enough:

Macro defined in mac.clj

```
(ns nut.mac)

(defmacro def-foo
  "Define a trivial function in the *current* namespace named ``fn-name''."
  [fn-name]
  `(defn ~(symbol fn-name) [] ~(str "It's " fn-name ".")))

;; (macroexpand '(def-foo "bar"))
;; => (def bar (clojure.core/fn ([] "It's bar.")))
```

Macro invoked in foo.cljs

```
(ns nut.foo
  (:require-macros [nut.mac :refer [def-foo def-ns-foo]]))

(def-foo "a-function") ;; creates nut.foo.a-function
```

I'd like the macro to create a function in a different namespace.
Something like this (won't work):

```
(ns nut.mac)

(defmacro def-ns-foo
  "Define a trivial function in the *specified* namespace named ``fn-name''."
  [namespace-name fn-name]
  `(do (ns ~(symbol namespace-name))
       (defn ~(symbol fn-name) [] ~(str "It's " fn-name "."))))

;; (macroexpand '(def-ns-foo "nut.x" "bar"))
;; => (do (clojure.core/ns nut.x) (clojure.core/defn bar [] "It's bar."))
```

Then invoke the macro in the nut.foo namespace:

```
(ns nut.foo
  (:require-macros [nut.mac :refer [def-ns-foo]]))

(def-ns-foo "nut.x" "baz")
;; WARNING: Use of undeclared Var cljs.core/ns at line 8
```

It's pretty clear that a ns form at the top-level of a file is treated specially at compile time.

Something like this works (all in one file) but it's kind of tedious:

```
(ns nut.foo
  (:require-macros [nut.mac :refer [def-foo]]))

(ns nut.x)
(def-foo "baz")

(ns nut.y)
(def-foo "baz")

(ns nut.z)
(def-foo "baz")
```

I've started looking at cljs.analyzer.api, but honestly understanding that may be more trouble than it's worth at this point.

Is creating a namespace in a Clojurescript macro impossible, or maybe just wrong?